# RavenDB Multimap index - documents not in both collections

Tags: ravendb

I know how to do this in SQL world, but trying to figure this out in RavenDB land.

I have 2 classes as such:

```
public class Client
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class WaitingListEntry
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string ClientId {get;set;}
  public string OtherDocumentInformation {get;set;}
}
```

And a fairly straightforward map/reduce:

```
AddMap<Client>(clients => from c in clients select new { Id = (string)null, ClientId = c.ClientId, Name = c.Name });

AddMap<WaitingListEntry>(wls => from wl in wls select new { Id = wl.Id, ClientId = wl.ClientId, Name = (string)null });

Reduce = results => from result in results
  group result by result.ClientId
  into g
  select new { Id = g.Select(x => x.Id).Where(x => x != null).First(),
    ClientId = g.Key,
    Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).Where(x => x != null).First()
  };
```

The wrinkle I'm running into is that not all clients are in the waiting list, and I want to exclude those from the index. I'm used to SQL thinking and can't figure out what to do here to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `multimap index`. With the `Index` below you can get get all your waiting lists with the client:

[image: Index]

And you'll get the result:

[image]

I've used this data:

```
session.Store(new Client() { Id = "client/1", Name = "Client 1" });
session.Store(new Client() { Id = "client/2", Name = "Client 2" });
session.Store(new Client() { Id = "client/3", Name = "Client 3" });

session.Store(new WaitingListEntry() { Id = "waitingListEntry/1", ClientId = "client/1", OtherDocumentInformation = "Info" });
session.Store(new WaitingListEntry() { Id = "waitingListEntry/2", ClientId = "client/2", OtherDocumentInformation = "Info" });

session.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Oh man I'm a fool. I was doing LoadDocument inside my transformer, had no idea I could do it as well in the Map. Thanks!

Comment: Although you can use LoadDocument to index related documents it is advisable to create a map/reduce index instead. For instance, "Using the LoadDocument adds a loaded document to the tracking list. This may cause very expensive calculations to occur, especially when multiple documents are tracking the same document".